# Is there a rule that forbids to name its entity class "User" when working with PostgreSQL and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

guys. I'm having a problem with a Spring boot 2.3.0  and PostgreSQL 12 project. I have an entity class I called User whose code is as follows:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

And my application.properties file looks like this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*********
```

The concern is that when I execute my project I get a mistake like this:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table if exists user cascade" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « user »
  Position : 22
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:310) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:296) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2020-05-24 06:16:33.429  WARN 13636 --- [         task-1] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table user (id int8 generated by default as identity, age int4 not null, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (id int8 generated by default as identity, age int4 not null, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « user »
  Position : 14
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:310) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:296) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

However when I change the name of my class e.g. to Person

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

I don't get any errors. Could someone help me with this in the following way or at least explain me what is wrong with the entity class User.
I would also like to add that when in doubt I tested this code with MySQL as an alternative to PostgreSQL and got no errors.

Comment: this is a problem with H2 database as well. I was getting incorrect SQL syntax errors and hours later I found this and tried it and it started working. Good Question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In PostgreSQL `user` is a reserved keyword. Use quotes like `"user"` for table name using `@Table`

```
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User {
```

Better naming for table name is to use a plural form like `users`.

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
```

Answer (score 6):

user is a reserved word in SQL and Postgres. To avoid this, either you change the table name or define the table name as `` @Table(name="`user`") ``

please check 
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/quote/User.java#L31

Answer (score 0):

I was using `user` as a table name. changing it to `@Table(name="users")` worked for me.

Comment: Duplicated, same as accepted answer.